# Running Java Plugins in Fiji using Jython: Exception java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [D

Tags: java, plugins, jython, imagej

I'm writing a jython script to manipulate images in Fiji. Specifically, I am trying to track cell outlines by implementing the a subset of the classes from the JFilament plugin (TwoDContourDeformation and IntensityEnergy. See https://github.com/odinsbane/jfilament/tree/master/src/main/java/snakeprogram).

I am able to successfully construct a TwoDContourDeformation object, however when I try to call the addSnakePoints method on my object, I consistently receive the following exception: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [D

I understand this exception generally refers to trying to load a Double object into an array or class that is not constructed to accept those types. However, it is not clear where/what the Double object is or where it is running into an error in the addSnakePoints method within the TwoDContourDeformation class. Here is my code:

```python
#IMPORTS
import java.util
from ij import IJ
from snakeprogram import IntensityEnergy
from snakeprogram import TwoDContourDeformation

#CONSTANTS
initial_parameters = java.util.Arrays.asList()
initial_parameters.add(1.0)
initial_parameters.add(2000.0)
initial_parameters.add(40.0)
initial_parameters.add(1.0)
initial_parameters.add(10.0)
initial_parameters.add(1000.0)
initial_parameters.add(1.0)

tracking_parameters = java.util.ArrayList()
tracking_parameters.add(1.0)
tracking_parameters.add(2000.0)
tracking_parameters.add(40.0)
tracking_parameters.add(1.0)
tracking_parameters.add(10.0)
tracking_parameters.add(5.0)
tracking_parameters.add(3.0)

def set_parameters(deform, initial_parameters):

    deform.setAlpha(initial_parameters[0])
    deform.setBeta(initial_parameters[1])
    deform.setGamma(initial_parameters[2])
    deform.setWeight(initial_parameters[3])
    deform.setStretch(initial_parameters[4])

    return None

def set_parameters_deform(edges, outline, num_slice, initial_parameters, tracking_parameters):
'''
Sets parameters for JFilament and deforms snake around cell edges
Inputs:
   edges: ImagePlus, binary image stack
   outline: java.util.ArrayList, x coordinates for the initial snake
   num_slice: int, initial frame of the image stack
   initial_parameters: java.util.ArrayList, list of starting parameters
   tracking_parameters: java.util.ArrayList, list of parameters for tracking through all frames of the image stack

Returns:
     outline: java.util.ArrayList, list of java.util.ArrayList. Length is equal to number of frames 
'''

deform = TwoDContourDeformation(outline, IntensityEnergy(edges.getProcessor(), 1.0))
if num_slice == 1:
    set_parameters(deform, initial_parameters)
    for i in xrange(initial_parameters[5]):
        try:
            deform.addSnakePoints(initial_parameters[6])
              #the above line is where the Exception is thrown
            deform.deformSnake()
        except ValueError:
            IJ.log('snake failure')

set_parameters(deform, tracking_parameters)
for i in xrange(initial_parameters[5]):
    try:
        deform.addSnakePoints(tracking_parameters[6])
        deform.deformSnake()
    except ValueError:
        IJ.log('snake failure')

return outline

edges = IJ.getImage()
x_coords = [49.71320343559643, 49.702736000251505, 49.67134402431167, 49.619058487867186, 49.54593099043001, 49.45203370001131, 49.33745928190039]
#length of x_coords list shortened for brevity

jx = java.util.ArrayList()
for x in x_coords:
    jx.add(float(x))

set_parameters_deform(edges, jx, 1, initial_parameters, tracking_parameters):
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry about this, the points aren't just the x coordinates, the name is a bit of a legacy artifact. I should take a bit to fix that. They need to be double[]'s of length 2.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with either the scripting framework or the JFilament plugin.

The following Python minimal example reproduces the issue:

```python
# @ImagePlus edges

from java.util import ArrayList
from snakeprogram.energies import IntensityEnergy
from snakeprogram import TwoDContourDeformation

outline = ArrayList()
outline.add(1.0)
outline.add(2.0)
outline.add(3.0)

deform = TwoDContourDeformation(outline, IntensityEnergy(edges.getProcessor(), 1.0))
deform.addSnakePoints(1000.0)
print deform
```

as well as this Groovy example:

```groovy
// @ImagePlus edges

import snakeprogram.energies.IntensityEnergy
import snakeprogram.TwoDContourDeformation

outline = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
deform = new TwoDContourDeformation(outline, new IntensityEnergy(edges.getProcessor(), 1.0))
deform.addSnakePoints((double)1000.0)
print deform
```

Both point to this line as the source of error:

```
at snakeprogram.TwoDContourDeformation.addSnakePoints(TwoDContourDeformation.java:101)
```

https://github.com/odinsbane/jfilament/blob/master/src/main/java/snakeprogram/TwoDContourDeformation.java#L101

with scripting-specific conversion exceptions:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [D

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to [D
```

In both cases, an array of double (`[D`) is expected, but only a single number instance is provided. You could try contacting @odinsbane on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

Comment: The points need to be double[]'s of length 2. I hadn't seen this question before so this is a bit late.